# Is יותר מלימודו time dependent?

Tags: halacha, purim

The Ramma in siman 695 quotes the famous opinions that when drinking wine on Purim, one fulfills his obligation by drinking more than he usually does and going to sleep.

> ויש אומרים דאין צריך להשתכר כל כך אלא שישתה יותר מלימודו ויישן ומתוך שיישן אינו יודע בין ארור המן לברוך מרדכי

My question is if this amount that he usually drinks depends on the time of the day? For instance, if one drinks ten ounces every night at supper and never drinks in the morning, will he fulfill this opinion by drinking six ounces in the morning (and taking a nap)?

Comment: It seems like the point is probably to drink a little more than you are used to, since whatever you used to wont affect you much. Accordingly, if you are used to drinking at night, you would drink more than that in the day. Parenthetically, by this reasoning if a person normally gets drunk, then this would be irrelevant since he has not acclimated to that amount of drinking anyway. Indeed, in the source for this, the Orehot Hayyim, _yoter milimudo m'at_ is presented in contradistinction to drunkenness. This is consistent with the above

Comment: וחייב אדם לבסומי בפוריא לא שישתכר שהשכרות איסור גמור ואין לך עבירה גדולה מזו שגורם לגילוי עריות ושפיכות דמים וכמה עבירות זולתן אך שישתה יותר מלימודו מעט כדי שירבה לשמוח

Comment: In this regard, see R. Yitshak Yosef, ילקוט יוסף קצוש"ע אורח חיים סימן תרצה - דיני סעודת פורים:  
אלא רק שישתה מעט יותר מלימודו. דהיינו התחלת שכרות. He seems to understand like I do that the point is to get a little drunk, by slightly exceeding your tolerance. Accordingly, if your tolerance is not dependent on the day, neither would this opinion be suchly dependent.

Comment: I'm not sure. Personally I would lean more towards the other side of the argument, but I'm not sure. I was hoping for something more definitive.

Comment: I agree that the above sources arent crystal clear. That's why I didn't post them as answer. R. Yitshak Yosef, however, does seem pretty clear, so it might justify an answer. Do you disagree with the implication of his words?

Comment: I'm not clear what you see more in his words than the ramma. The fact that he calls it being tipsy?  I would assume that is what the ramma meant himself.

Comment: נראה למבקש: אפשר לחקור בדברי הרמ"א האם כונתו לשיעור שכרות, פי' שישתה עד כדי שישתכר מעט מחמת מאינו מורגל ומלומד בכך, או דלמא הוי שיעור בשתיה עצמה, ולא בשכרות הבאה מחמתה. ולפי"ז אולי ההסבר דיעשה דבר מסוים להיכר חשיבות היום, לעשות אתם ימי משתה ושמחה. וזו באה מחמת האי-רגילות של מעשיו. ולאדם שאינו שותה יין ושכר כלל, כבר עשה כן בשתייה פורתא אף בלא שכרות כלל, והימים האלה נזכרים ונעשים מחמת שהם ימי משתה ושמחה. ונחזור לשאלה; מי שרגיל ביום ולא בלילה. לפי הצד הא' לא יועיל ולא כלום בשתיתו הרגילה, אבל לפי הצד הב' לכאו' יועיל. ומדברי הראש"ל משמע כצד הב', ודוק

Comment: This isnt the topic of the question, but Rama likely holds like the numerous Rishonim and Aharonim who hold that the entire gemara is either not accepted halakhically, or a mitsva b'alma but not an obligation. According, using the term yotse is a bit misleading.

Comment: Nirah limevaqesh in place of nira li. Nice play on words:)